# Intercept an error when calling a rest endpoint in JHipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

Been trying to get my auth-expired.interceptor.ts to fire when I call a change a page where some information gets called and the restpoint throws a 401 error.

I can see error in the console, but the AuthInterceptor is not being called. Not sure if it is possible this.

Appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer after trying many things. My problem was the rest service was in a *lazy loaded module*. The **customHttpProvider()** was being loaded from the main module, but I also need it to include it in the **providers** of my *lazy loaded module*.  Once I did that, the rest endpoints interceptors started working fine.